# Can't install redux-mock-store: 404 Not Found - GET lodash.isplainobject

Tags: node.js, npm, lodash, redux-mock-store, packagecloud.io

I am trying to install redux-mock-store using npm.
I am using node 16.10.0.
But, I keep getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/lodash.isplainobject/-/lodash.isplainobject-4.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'lodash.isplainobject@https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/lodash.isplainobject/-/lodash.isplainobject-4.0.6.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2023-10-30T16_21_48_489Z-debug-0.log
```

Other modules get installed normally. No idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a node compatibility issue.
I switched to node 14 and it worked.

Not sure why that's the case. But, it solved it.

If this happens to you, you'll probably need to switch to a specific version of node.

If anyone got an explanation for why switching to node solved this please let me know. As this issue happened to many times. And I always solve it by switching node versions.